# direct sums, kernel and linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, direct-sum

could you please help me solve the given problem below?

Let $f$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over $F$.

If $$
1+1 \ne 0 \hspace{1cm} \text{and} \hspace{1cm} f^2=2f, 
$$

show that $$
V=\ker(f) \oplus \ker(f-2\operatorname{id}_V).  
$$

I'm new to linear algebra and still struggling with direct sums, kernel and linear transformations. Tell me where to start and kindly guide me if my answer is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some hints. Set $g=f-2\mathrm{id}_V$ for simplicity.

1. You want to prove that every $v\in V$ can be written *in a unique way* as $v=x+y$, with $x\in\ker(f)$ and $y\in\ker(g)=\ker(f-2\mathrm{id}_V)$
2. For every $v\in V$, you have $f(g(v))=0=g(f(v))$
3. For every $v\in V$, $2v=f(v)+(2v-f(v))=f(v)-g(v)$